# Center the text of a column to the middle of the square

Tags: tables

Right now I'm struggling to center the content of the column on the left to fit the square in the middle. Would appreciate any guidance

[image: ![enter image description here]

This is my current code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Para usar em enumerações

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{8cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Necessidades das Empresas}} & \textbf{Tarefas e Aplicações} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Automatização de processos} &
    \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
        \item Correção de falhas na cobrança de serviços através de sistemas de faturação, ao extrair informação de múltiplas fontes;
        \item Leitura de documentos legais e contratuais para extrair provisões, utilizando processamento em linguagem natural.
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Visão cognitiva} &
    \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
        \item Prever o que um determinado cliente é suscetível de comprar;
        \item Identificar a fraude de crédito em tempo real e detetar fraudes em reclamações de seguros;
        \item Automatizar a segmentação personalizada de anúncios digitais.
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Envolver clientes e colaboradores} &
    \begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
        \item Suporte instantâneo e personalizado;
        \item Resolução rápida de consultas frequentes, melhorando a experiência do cliente e reduzindo tempos de espera;
        \item Monitoramento das redes sociais e outras plataformas para análise de sentimento.
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Tabela de Necessidades das Empresas e respetivas Tarefas/Aplicações.}
  \label{necessities_tabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Are you looking to center the contents of the left-hand column vertically? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

- I took a liberty and edited your question that now can be tested as it is.
- the shorter solution is load `array` package in document preamble and change `{|p{6cm}|p{8cm}|}` to `{|m{6cm}|m{8cm}|}`. Then you will get

[image]

However, you may consider to use `tabularray` package for writing your table in more compact form:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Para usar em enumerações
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlist{nosep, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tblr}{ hlines, vlines,
               colspec = {X[0.5,l, m] X[1.5,l,m] },
               stretch = -1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                            % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
               row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries},
               rowsep  = 5 pt,
               measure = vbox,
               }
Necessidades das Empresas
    &   Tarefas e Aplicações            \\
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Correção de falhas na cobrança de serviços através de sistemas de faturação, ao extrair informação de múltiplas fontes;
        \item Leitura de documentos legais e contratuais para extrair provisões, utilizando processamento em linguagem natural.
    \end{itemize}   \\
Visão cognitiva
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Prever o que um determinado cliente é suscetível de comprar;
    \item Identificar a fraude de crédito em tempo real e detetar fraudes em reclamações de seguros;
    \item Automatizar a segmentação personalizada de anúncios digitais.
        \end{itemize}   \\
Envolver clientes e colaboradores
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Suporte instantâneo e personalizado;
    \item Resolução rápida de consultas frequentes, melhorando a experiência do cliente e reduzindo tempos de espera;
    \item Monitoramento das redes sociais e outras plataformas para análise de sentimento.
        \end{itemize}   \\
Automatização de processos
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Correção de falhas na cobrança de serviços através de sistemas de faturação, ao extrair informação de múltiplas fontes;
        \item Leitura de documentos legais e contratuais para extrair provisões, utilizando processamento em linguagem natural.
    \end{itemize}   \\
Visão cognitiva
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Prever o que um determinado cliente é suscetível de comprar;
    \item Identificar a fraude de crédito em tempo real e detetar fraudes em reclamações de seguros;
    \item Automatizar a segmentação personalizada de anúncios digitais.
        \end{itemize}   \\
Envolver clientes e colaboradores
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Suporte instantâneo e personalizado;
    \item Resolução rápida de consultas frequentes, melhorando a experiência do cliente e reduzindo tempos de espera;
    \item Monitoramento das redes sociais e outras plataformas para análise de sentimento.
        \end{itemize}   \\
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{Tabela de Necessidades das Empresas e respetivas Tarefas/Aplicações.}
  \label{necessities_tabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may liked the following more professional looks of table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Para usar em enumerações
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlist{nosep, itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[0.5,l] X[1.5,l },
           stretch = -1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                        % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
           row{1}  = {c, m, font=\bfseries},
           row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 7pt},
           measure = vbox,
           }
  \toprule
Necessidades das Empresas
    &   Tarefas e Aplicações            \\
    \midrule
Automatização de processos
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Correção de falhas na cobrança de serviços através de sistemas de faturação, ao extrair informação de múltiplas fontes;
        \item Leitura de documentos legais e contratuais para extrair provisões, utilizando processamento em linguagem natural.
    \end{itemize}   \\
Visão cognitiva
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Prever o que um determinado cliente é suscetível de comprar;
    \item Identificar a fraude de crédito em tempo real e detetar fraudes em reclamações de seguros;
    \item Automatizar a segmentação personalizada de anúncios digitais.
        \end{itemize}   \\
Envolver clientes e colaboradores
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Suporte instantâneo e personalizado;
    \item Resolução rápida de consultas frequentes, melhorando a experiência do cliente e reduzindo tempos de espera;
    \item Monitoramento das redes sociais e outras plataformas para análise de sentimento.
        \end{itemize}   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{Tabela de Necessidades das Empresas e respetivas Tarefas/Aplicações.}
  \label{necessities_tabel}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hard-code the column widths, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, set its target width to `\textwidth`, and employ the `X` column type for the right-hand column. I'd further employ the machinery of the `enumitem` package to create a bespoke, itemize-like environment for the lists in the right-hand column; see the code below for a way to implement this idea. Oh, and I think it's neither necessary nor advisable to render the contents of the header cells in **bold-face**.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian'?
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt, nosep,
                       before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
                       after=\end{minipage}}

\newlength\mylen % new length parameter, to hold width of left-hand col.

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Tabela de Necessidades das Empresas e respetivas Tarefas\slash Aplicações.}
  \label{necessities_tabel}

  \settowidth{\mylen}{Automatização de processos} % compute width of left-hand column
  \medskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
        >{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen} % suspend full justification
        >{\RaggedRight}X         % suspend full justification
        @{}}
    \toprule 
    Necessidades das Empresas & Tarefas e Aplicações \\
    \midrule
    Automatização de processos &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Correção de falhas na cobrança de serviços através de sistemas de faturação, ao extrair informação de múltiplas fontes;
    \item Leitura de documentos legais e contratuais para extrair provisões, utilizando processamento em linguagem natural.
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \addlinespace
    Visão cognitiva &
    \begin{tabitemize}
        \item Prever o que um determinado cliente é suscetível de comprar;
        \item Identificar a fraude de crédito em tempo real e detetar fraudes em reclamações de seguros;
        \item Automatizar a segmentação personalizada de anúncios digitais.
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \addlinespace
    Envolver clientes e colaboradores &
    \begin{tabitemize}
        \item Suporte instantâneo e personalizado;
        \item Resolução rápida de consultas frequentes, melhorando a experiência do cliente e reduzindo tempos de espera;
        \item Monitoramento das redes sociais e outras plataformas para análise de sentimento.
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```